# How to return only numbers from query where column is nvarchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a simple query that is returning records where "column2" > 0

Here is the data in the database

```
Column1          Column2
1                123456789
2                123456781
3                13-151-1513
4                alsdjf
5                 
6                000000000
```

Her is the query

```
 select column1, replace(a.Payroll_id,'-','')
    from table1
    where isnumeric(column2) = 1
```

I'd like to return the following:

```
Column1          Column2
1                123456789
2                123456781
3                131511513
```

This mean, I won't select any records when the column is blank (or null), will not return a row if it's not an integer, and will drop out the '-', and would not show row 6 since it's all 0.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use something like this :

```
USE tempdb
GO
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
ID INT IDENTITY
,VALUE VARCHAR(30)
)
INSERT INTO #Temp (VALUE) VALUES ('1213213'), ('1213213'), ('121-32-13'), ('ASDFASF2123')
GO
WITH CteData
AS
(
SELECT REPLACE(VALUE,'-','') as Valor FROM #Temp 
)
SELECT * FROM CteData WHERE (ISNUMERIC(Valor) = 1 AND valor not like '%[0-0]%')
DROP TABLE #Temp
```

then you can apply validations for empty, NULL,0 etc

Comment: Be careful here. There are plenty of non-numbers that will convince the ISNUMERIC function that it is in fact a number. Add another value like '1e4'. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/ISNUMERIC()/71512/

Comment: And only grabs hyphens to remove, not any other special chars.

Comment: I just followed what the story mentioned "and will drop out the '-'", I can apply different validations to avoid the scenarios related for special chars (nothing hard to do) , critics are accepted but also provide solutions or different ways to do something. that's why we are all here to share our knowlegde.:)

Comment: Can you please share your code or update the question?, in my example I'm using a CTE so not sure how you are getting the error.

Comment: Sorry - It works with the Isnumeric, but I also don't want anything that's '0'

Comment: Do you mean '0' or just 0?

Comment: Blank, or '0000000' see column 6 in my table

Comment: Your new update doesn't work.. If I add %[0-0]% no records returned

Comment: You got me on the right track... I ended up using Case When in the select statement, and made the main query a sub query.  Then used the > 0 to filter results of the sub query.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: nice to know everything is running smoothly now.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL2012 or above you can also use `TRY_PARSE` that is more selective in its parsing. This function will return `NULL` if a record can't be converted. You could use it like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
    (
     ID INT IDENTITY ,
     VALUE VARCHAR(30)
    )
INSERT  INTO #temp
       ( VALUE )
VALUES  ( '1213213' ),
       ( '1213213' ),
       ( '121-32-13' ),
       ( 'ASDFASF2123' ),
       ( '0000000' )

SELECT  ParsedValue
FROM   #temp
       CROSS APPLY ( SELECT TRY_PARSE(
                          Value AS INT ) AS ParsedValue
                ) details
WHERE   ParsedValue IS NOT NULL
AND ParsedValue>0
```